# How to get Parts that have two different value source type?

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2014, temp-tables, sql-server-2017, aggregates

I work on sql server 2017 i need to get  part id that have `two different source type`
per same `part` .

but  part have two different source type per part

and it must have one source type from two source type equal 8901 .

sample data

```
create table #temp
     (
     partid int,
     sourcetypeid int
     )
     insert into #temp(partid,sourcetypeid)
     values
     (1290,5012),
     (1290,5012),
     (1290,8901),
     (3501,5402),
     (3501,74430),
     (7001,8901),
     (7321,8900),
     (2040,5090),
     (2040,5400),
     (7321,7400),
     (9110,8901),
     (9110,8901)
```

what i try

```
select partid from #temp
 where sourcetypeid=8901
 group by partid
 having count(distinct sourcetypeid)=2
```

but it return `null`

expected result

[partid that have two different source type at least source type 8901 must exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okNSA.png)

Comment: It's always good to indicate which version of sql server you're using. However, for future questions *also* include the general [sql-server] tag too, because it gets a lot more traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but it return null

The current query fails because the WHERE clause excludes all sourceTypeId except *one*: 8901.

```
PartId | SourceTypeId
-----: | -----------:
  1290 |         8901
  7001 |         8901
  9110 |         8901
  9110 |         8901
```

So when the HAVING clause searches for parts with two (2) SourceTypeId values, no matches are found, because the count is always `1`:

```
PartId | COUNT(DISTINCT t.SourceTypeId)
-----: | -----------------------------:
  1290 |    1
  7001 |    1
  9110 |    1
```

Instead, try using EXISTS to ensure that one of two SourceTypeId's is 8901:

```
SELECT t.PartId
FROM   #temp t 
WHERE  EXISTS (
       SELECT 1
       FROM  #temp r
       WHERE r.SourceTypeId = 8901
       AND   r.partId = t.PartId
)
GROUP BY  t.PartId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.SourceTypeId)=2
```

**Result:**

```
| PartId |
| -----: |
|   1290 |
```